# The application Passwords and Keys has closed unexpectedly

Tags: gnome, system-installation, 20.04, wayland, seahorse

[image: Error message screenshot]

[image: Details]

About the installation: Ubuntu 20.04 — Clean installation with these options:

- Minimal installation
- Custom partitions
- Download updates while installing
- Install third-party software
- Wayland session

I've also tried reinstalling without luck. It appears about one or five minutes after logging in. The updates are up-to-date.

Comment: I am just guessing, wonder if minimal install is missing something that seahouse needs or because of wayland.  Partitions have plenty of free space?

Comment: Did you use same ISO and/or same USB or download new one, or did you just remove and reinstall seahouse?

Comment: @crip659 yes they have plenty of free space.

Comment: @crip659 I installed it about three times the past week with different downloaded ISO and as I said it's a clean install I didn't touch anything. I can try to reinstall seahorse but I wonder why it happens because in the past (about a year ago) I installed Ubuntu Budgie and the same error appears.

Comment: With Ubuntu Budgie was it also a minimal install using Wayland?  Do you have Xorg(non wayland) session you can try and see if problem persists?  Seahorse usually quite stable program, just works.

Comment: With Ubuntu Budgie it was a normal installation with Xorg (I didn't know about Wayland in those days). I'm going to do a normal installation with Xorg and see what happens.

Comment: @kahnmeither I can confirm this. I have an Ubuntu which is only some weeks old and seahorse crashed. I'm not sure you have the exact same issue because your details lack of detail :) For me, it's [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/seahorse/+bug/1832811) which isn't solved yet.

Answer (score 0):

I think Password and Keys is the "seahorse" application (?). You might want to file a bug report over there, they might be able to help.

https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/seahorse/-/issues

Comment: After committing the bounty, I realized I should have given the specific bug. I had written it in the comments below OP's questions. [This bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/seahorse/+bug/1832811) is the exact assertion that fails. What I intended with the bounty was maybe get the attention of someone who is experienced with seahorse and can say something about why this happens. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Copy '/usr/share/gnupg' to your home directory `sudo cp -r /usr/share/gnupg ~/.gnupg` and then reboot and see if that works.

Comment: After committing the bounty, I realized I should have given the specific bug. I had written it in the comments below OP's questions. [This bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/seahorse/+bug/1832811) is the exact assertion that fails. What I intended with the bounty was maybe get the attention of someone who is experienced with seahorse and can say something about why this happens. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by removing my .gnupg directory from my home folder.

```
rm -rf ~/.gnupg
```

You might want just move it instead of deleting it so you have a backup though. After restart it had regenerated a new `.gnupg` folder. Even though I had deleted it, I still have all my saved passwords/logins available in Seahorse.

Comment: what does this store?